# PHP: Include php variable in shell_exec

Tags: php, bash

Can I include a php variable in shell_exec?

I'm tring to make this line work $Dname is a php variable

```
shell_exec(cat . $Dname.txt . | sed "s#,]}#]}#g" > $Dname2.txt);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not quoted your shell command, and you should escape `$Dname` with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/function.escapeshellarg.php). Note I have also escaped the quotes in the `sed` expression, though in this case they could be changed to single quotes without negative effects.

```
$Dname = escapeshellarg($Dname);
shell_exec("cat $Dname.txt . | sed \"s#,]}#]}#g\" > {$Dname}2.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but like any other string in PHP, this needs quoting:

```
shell_exec('cat '.$Dname.'.txt | sed "s#,]}#]}#g" > '.$Dname2.'.txt');
```

You should escape user input, if necessary, with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).